# Multline & Splitfrac

Tags: equations, fractions, multline

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
-\dfrac{1}{64\pi^2}
\left[     
      \dfrac{
        \splitfrac{
            (m_2-m_3)(2y_e^2-y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2
              }{
              + (y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 )\cos2{\theta_{23})\sin\delta^2\sin\theta_{12}^2\sin2\theta_{13}}
              }
        }{
          m_2+m_3
         }\\
    + \dfrac{
      \splitfrac{
              (m_2 + m_3)\cos\delta\sin\theta_{12}(\cos\delta(2y_e^2-y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 + (y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 )\cos2\theta_{23})\sin\theta_{12}\sin2\theta_{13}
            }{
            + 2(y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2)\cos\theta_{12}\cos\theta_{13}\sin2\theta_{23})
            }
        }{
          m_2-m_3
         }\\
    + \dfrac{
         \splitfrac{ 
          2(m_1+m_3)\cos\delta\cos\theta_{12}\cos\theta_{13}(\cos\delta\cos\theta_{12}
          }{
        (2y_e^2-y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 + (y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 )\cos2\theta_{23})\sin\theta_{13}+(-y_\mu^2+y_\tau^2)\sin\theta_{12}\sin2\theta_{23}
           }
         }{
             m_1-m_3
          }\\
    +\dfrac{1}
             {
              \splitfrac{
                         (m_1+m_3)2(m_1+m_3)\cos\theta_{12}\cos\theta_{13}\sin\delta(y_\mu^2
                        }{
                          -y_\tau^2 )\cos\delta\sin\delta\sin\theta_{12}\sin2\theta_{23}
                         }{
                           +\sin\delta(\cos\theta_{12}(2y_e^2-y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2+(y_\mu^2
                         }{
                            -y_\tau^2)\cos2\theta_{23}\sin\theta_{13}+(-y_\mu^2 + y_\tau^2)\cos\delta\sin\theta_{12}\sin2\theta_{23}
                         }
              }
 \right]            
 \end{multline*}


\end{document}
```

On compiling this code in  KILE it gives the following error

```
Missing \right.inserted \end{multline*}

Extra \right \end{multline*}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Best to get rid of (or comment out) the pair of `\left[` and `\right]` statements entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have unpaired `\left` and `\right` commands. You need to add a `\right.` and `\left.` to match the ones on the first and last lines of the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
-\dfrac{1}{64\pi^2}
\left[     
      \dfrac{
        \splitfrac{
            (m_2-m_3)(2y_e^2-y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2
              }{
              + (y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 )\cos2{\theta_{23})\sin\delta^2\sin\theta_{12}^2\sin2\theta_{13}}
              }
        }{
          m_2+m_3
         }
    \right.%<-------------------HERE
    \\
    + \dfrac{
      \splitfrac{
              (m_2 + m_3)\cos\delta\sin\theta_{12}(\cos\delta(2y_e^2-y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 + (y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 )\cos2\theta_{23})\sin\theta_{12}\sin2\theta_{13}
            }{
            + 2(y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2)\cos\theta_{12}\cos\theta_{13}\sin2\theta_{23})
            }
        }{
          m_2-m_3
         }\\
    + \dfrac{
         \splitfrac{ 
          2(m_1+m_3)\cos\delta\cos\theta_{12}\cos\theta_{13}(\cos\delta\cos\theta_{12}
          }{
        (2y_e^2-y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 + (y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2 )\cos2\theta_{23})\sin\theta_{13}+(-y_\mu^2+y_\tau^2)\sin\theta_{12}\sin2\theta_{23}
           }
         }{
             m_1-m_3
          }\\
    \left. %<-------------------HERE
    +\dfrac{1}
             {
              \splitfrac{
                         (m_1+m_3)2(m_1+m_3)\cos\theta_{12}\cos\theta_{13}\sin\delta(y_\mu^2
                        }{
                          -y_\tau^2 )\cos\delta\sin\delta\sin\theta_{12}\sin2\theta_{23}
                         }{
                           +\sin\delta(\cos\theta_{12}(2y_e^2-y_\mu^2-y_\tau^2+(y_\mu^2
                         }{
                            -y_\tau^2)\cos2\theta_{23}\sin\theta_{13}+(-y_\mu^2 + y_\tau^2)\cos\delta\sin\theta_{12}\sin2\theta_{23}
                         }
              }
 \right]            
 \end{multline*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...but the last fraction goes outside the margin of the document

Comment: @Tanvir - The additional problem you raise in the comment isn't related to the one you raised in this posting. The solution to the additional problem should follow the lines contained in the answers to your earlier posting.